# how Deploy asp.net application on windows azure..?

Tags: .net, mysql, oracle

I have created a media player in asp.net and now I want to deploy this application on windows azure. Which role can I use to deploy this application? Also, can anyone tell me the procedure for this?

Comment: You have given very few details.  What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? If you have not researched this using Lord Google perhaps you should begin there.

Answer (score 0):

It is a question with huge expectation however I will try to help you the same way i did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527517/how-to-migrate-existing-asp-net-mvc-3-project-with-mdf-file-sql-2008-to-windo/10528154#10528154).

As it is big question and you will have to work in parts to get everything done. The following steps are written with understanding that you do have Windows Azure subscription and have basic understanding of ASP.net, IIS, and VS2010.

First and foremost, you will be using a ASP.NET Web Role to get your application running in Windows Azure.

**Step 1:** Install Windows Azure SDK 1.6 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=234939&clcid=0x409

**Step 2:** After that, open your ASP.NET application and when you right click on solution you will find a new option as "Add Windows Azure Deployment Project", select it. Be sure that your ASP.NET application is web Application.

You will see a new Windows Azure project is created in your solution name your_application_name.Azure (default) is created. At this time if you make Azure project as your "Startup" application and run it, your ASP.NET application will run inside Windows Azure Compute Emulator.

**Step 3:** Verify your code for any problem and fix it. Be sure to test in Compute Emulator and this is the time please learn about Service Configuration and Service Definition with your Windows Azure project.

**Step 4:** Once you have your ASP.NET application working in compute emulator, You are ready to deploy it. Finally now package your application and deploy to Windows Azure for deployment and final test. The step by step details are located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_introtowindowsazurelabvs2010_topic4#_Toc297905245):

**Step 0:** If you have time, I would suggest you to finish [this exercise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_introtowindowsazurelabvs2010_topic2#_Toc297905236) to learn more about ASP.NET Web Role, Azure SDK Environment and other things will will help you a lot later.