# Facebook C# SDK Azure documentation

Tags: c#, azure, facebook-c#-sdk

I am about to emabark on a project that will use Azure and Facebook C# SDK.  I was just wondering when will the documentation be available on the C# SDK website?  I have no idea where to begin and would love some documentation/tutorials.

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need some pointer about where to begin, I sure can give your some pointers but get ready for a time of adventure because you sure going to hit some hardtime. What you really need is to develop your project in two steps:

1. Create an ASP.NET (MVC?) Web application using FaceBook C# SDK
2. Convert this ASP.NET application to Web Role to deploy to Windows Azure

To start your development for 1) I would suggest following this Documentation:

1. http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/
2. http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/ajax-requests

I would also suggest to look SO for more assistance during your development when you hit errors as there are lots of solution discussed.

Finally when you come to 2) you can follow [how Deploy asp.net application on windows azure..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714018/how-deploy-asp-net-application-on-windows-azure/10724923#10724923)

Comment: Thanks, Avkash.  I am already half way there.  Well, not really.  I have a POC Facebook app that I built though.  :-)

Comment: Great then you just need to migrate as ASP.NET Web Role and then test locally in Compute Emulator. Once feel comfortable, deploy to Azure. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

> This documentation is in progress as of Feb. 11, 2012. We are working
>   on big improvements for the coming weeks.

Source: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/azure/

So yea, that's your answer.

Comment: IIRC there's general documentation for the SDK which should be applicable regardless of which specific platform you're building for

Comment: Leon, I saw that message on the C# SDK site.  I was just hoping for an update or an ETA.